# Code to change BG image doesn't work, but can change BG color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel

I am trying to change the background image depending on whether the user hovers over a Candidate button or a Recruiter button.

I have tried the following code (which worked in JS Fiddle) and it fails. I inserted a background-color command (see commented line) and that worked fine so I can only assume its related to the background-image line but I can't see what I've done wrong.

The images preload fine as I can inspect them in Chrome devtools,

This is my JS Fiddle Code: http://jsfiddle.net/bdenson/m7u4vn6u/

```
$(document).ready(function() {




        //Preload
        $('<img/>').hide().attr('src', '{{url("/img/candidate.jpg")}}').on ('load',function(){
            $('body').append($(this));
        });

        //Preload
        $('<img/>').hide().attr('src', '{{url("/img/recruiter.jpg")}}').on ('load',function(){
            $('body').append($(this));
        });

        // Change BG on Hover - candidate
        $('#cand').hover(function() {
            $('body').css('background-image', '{{url("/img/candidate.jpg")}}');
            //$('body').css('background-color', 'red');
        }, function() {
            $('body').css('background', '');
        });

        // Change BG on Hover - recruiter
        $('#rec').hover(function() {
            $('body').css('background-image', '{{url("/img/recruiter.jpg")}}');
        }, function() {
            $('body').css('background', '');
        });
    });
```

Comment: But what's the point? You want the image to stay as the background when the cursor is moved from the button?

Comment: No I want the BG image to show when the user hovers over the button. When the cursor is moved it reverts to the original bg (which is a blue-grey color)

Comment: When I'm checking your project on jsfiddle, it works perfectly...

Comment: do you have jQuery referenced on your live version? since you're using it^^

Comment: K.Daniek - Yes, thats my problem it works in JSFiddle but not in my site

@user2267175 - Yes, Jquery is referenced before this script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the jquery and replaced it with more modern webAPI.
I hope it's okay.

This should however work pretty much anywhere unless you're using some old dino-browser :), 
http://jsfiddle.net/m7u4vn6u/6/

```js
  var bod = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

  var pointerPref = "pointer";

  // Check support for pointer.
  if (!window.PointerEvent && !navigator.pointerEnabled) {
    pointerPref = "mouse";
  }

  //add a eventListener for mouse movement, run mMoveFunc on movement. 
  document.addEventListener(pointerPref + "move", mMoveFunc);

  function mMoveFunc(evt) {
    //catch event (evt) on mouse movement
    //If evt.target equals one of the buttons(hovering), change bg image.
    //It finds the buttons via the id, 
    //you can do it for any html element that takes a id attribute.
    if (evt.target === cand) {
      bod.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/40120/pexels-photo-40120.jpeg')";
    } else if (evt.target === rec) {
      bod.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/7366/startup-photos.jpg')";
    } else { //If none match, remove bg image and show default background.
      bod.style.backgroundImage = "";
    }

  }
```

```css
body {
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-color: darkgrey;

}

.preload {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  <image class="preload" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/40120/pexels-photo-40120.jpeg"/>
  <image class="preload" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7366/startup-photos.jpg"/>
  
  <div class="container">
    <button id="cand">Candidate</button>

    <button id="rec">Recruiter</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This works great- Thanks, but I'm not preloading the images now so there's a delay between first hover and image change.

Comment: @Baz I have no clue if it works, but i tried adding the images in image tags and setting a preload class which makes them invisible.
But i have never tried doing it before so it's a shot in the dark :)